# CakePHP 2.2.4: Afterfind Setup

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having an issue with afterfind() and none of what I'm reading has solved it. It has to do with the afterfind not working for related models which I am aware many people have brought up but I haven't found a solution. All the posts I see are also from 2009-2010.

User.php Model

```
function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
parent::afterFind($results, $primary);

if($primary){
    foreach($results as $key => $val){
        if (isset($val['User']['id'])){    
            $results[$key]['User']['online'] = $this->UsersOnline->find('count',
array('conditions' => array('UsersOnline.user_id =' => $val['User']['id'])));

// THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FOR USER MODEL PAGES     
        }
   }
}
else {
    foreach($results as $key => $val){
       $key['User']['online'] = $this->UsersOnline->find('count',
array('conditions' => array('UsersOnline.user_id =' => 1)));

// THIS IS THE PART THAT IS INCORRECT, AND THIS IS THE "BEST" SOLUTION
// I'VE FOUND ONLINE BUT IT IS NOT WORKING

/**
 * I've also tried these
 *
 * $results[$key]['online']
 * $results[$val]['online']
 * $results[$key][$val]['online']
 * $results['0']['User']['online']
 *
 * and about 5 other things
 */

    }
}

return $results;


} // end afterfind
```

I have tried many combinations of code in the "else" statement but I get one of three errors which are `Uninitialized string offset: 0`, `Cannot use string offset as an array` or `Column User.online not found`.

**EDIT:** Maybe this will provide a little more insight into the issue.

I'm trying to view the ARTICLES VIEW.CTP.
It displays the article at the top with `$article['User']` information (trying to include `$article['User']['online']`). Below the post are the article comments (`foreach $article['Comment'] as $comment`).

This is my ARTICLES.PHP CONTROLLER

```
public function view($page = null, $id = null) {

    // $this->Article->recursive = 3;

    $this->Article->id = $id;

    if (!$this->Article->exists()) {

        $this->Session->setFlash('This article does not exist');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'articles', 'action' => 'index'), null, true);
    }

    $this->Article->contain(array(
        'User' => array(
            'fields'=>array('User.username', 'User.signature', 'User.online'),
            'UserAvatar' => array(
                'fields'=>array('UserAvatar.file')
             )
        ),
        'Comment' => array(
            'fields'=>array('Comment.content', 'Comment.created', 'Comment.title'),
             'User' => array(
                'fields'=>array('User.username', 'User.signature', 'User.online'),
                'UserAvatar' => array(
                   'fields'=>array('UserAvatar.file')
                 )
              )
          )
     ));

    $this->set('article',  $this->Article->read(null, $id));

} // end view function
```

With the code as is (looking at the "contain" conditions, I am returned an error message "`Column User.online does not exist`". However, when I remove User.online from the contain on both the Comment array and the User array and INSTEAD set `$this->Article->recursive = 3`, I receive no error message. With recursive = 3, if I `print_r($article['User'])` or `print_r($comment['User'])` on articles view.ctp, the arrays both show the correct value for online.

The exact print for both $article['User'] and $comment['User'] with recursive = 3 is

```
Array
(
    [id] => this
    [username] => this
    [password] => ****
    [UserAvatar] => Array
        (
            [id] => this
            [column] => value
            [column] => value
        )
    [OTHER USER RELATED MODELS] => Array
        (
            [column] => value
        )
    [online] => 1
    [type] => 1
)
```

If I `echo $article['User']['online']` with recursive = 3, I get the correct value (3 is needed in order for UserAvatar info to display).

I don't understand why, then, with the contain, does it say that User.online cannot be found? I have `actAs = 'Containable'` in my AppModel because I use that property on nearly all models.

Here is my most updated USER.PHP MODEL afterfind()

```
function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
parent::afterFind($results, $primary);

     if($primary){
          foreach($results as $key => $val){
               if (isset($val['User']['id'])){    
                    $results[$key]['User']['online'] = $this->UsersOnline->find('count', array('conditions' => array('UsersOnline.user_id =' => $val['User']['id'])));
               }
          } // end for each
     } // end if primary
     else{
          foreach($results as $key => $val){
               if(isset($results['0']['User']['id'])){
                    $results['0']['User']['online'] = "1";
                      $results['User']['online'] = $results['0']['User']['online'];
                      $results['0']['User']['type'] = '1';
             }
               elseif(isset($results['User']['id'])){
                    $results['User']['online'] = "1";
                    $results[$key]['User']['online'] = $results['User']['online'];
                    $results['User']['type'] = '2';
               } // end elseif
                 // everything returns as type 1 so this may be irrelevant
          } // end for each
     } // end if not primary

      return $results;

} // end afterfind
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** After tinkering a little bit more I found out that the following works (Articles model) but this is not ideal because it retrieves all data from User and UserAvatar whereas I would like to fetch data only for specified fields. However, when I use the fields option, User.online is not recognized. Any ideas?

```
$this->Article->contain(array( 
         'User' => array(
            'UserAvatar'
        ),
          'Comment' => array(
             'User' => array(
                'UserAvatar'
              )
          )
     ));

 $this->set('article',  $this->Article->read(null, $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following foreach

```
foreach($results as &$val){
    $val['User']['online'] = $this->UsersOnline->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('UsersOnline.user_id' => 1)
    ));
}
```

Please note that this will only return the count where user_id=1

Comment: I receive "cannot use string offset as an array" on the line "$val['User']['online'] = $this->....."

Comment: Can you post the output of $val? $val is probably a string, which it should be in case of `$this->User->field('name')`. In that case you should skip this piece of code, because you don't need it.

Comment: I was using user_id = 1 to simplify things. I didn't want two incorrect variables on the same line.

Comment: You have not posted the output of $val. However, i noticed that CakePHP does not contain deeper models correctly when you dont provide the id and foreign_key in the field list. You could try this also.